# Object does not support this property or method:'IE.Firevent'

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to do IE automation using vb script. While automating the manual task using IE object, I am able to navigate to the website and enter value in text box, but the submit button available on website can only be triggered after a key up event is fired in that text box. So i did the IE.FireEvent("enableLoginButton()") but it is throwing the error :Object does not support this property or method:'IE.Firevent' . So, how can we proceed further in this? what is the substitute of this Fireevent?

Comment: If `enableLoginButton()` is a function, why don't you directly call it? Or why don't you just replicate what the function is doing?

Comment: can you give me the code snippet?